# Handling dynamic CSV headings in PHP/Mysql

Tags: php, parsing, codeigniter, csv

I know the title isn't the most descriptive, but I can't think of a better way to describe it.

Ultimately what I would like to do is this:

I am making a system that handles import of data via CSV from several different companies. Naturally, the format from each company is slightly different, with different amounts of data in each column/heading and a different arrangement.

I could either:

1. Hard code the file format into the program, which is quick and simple to program, but not abstract or future proof
2. **or** provide "dynamicity" by allowing users to configure "file formats" in the system, by dragging and dropping CSV headings and saving presets for each incoming file format.

I would like to do option 2, but how would I go about doing this?

I am guessing a tagging style system would do it... but any advice would be appreciated.

I am using PHP, MySQL, and CodeIgniter 2.0.2 if that helps, and also have access to all the Zend libraries in my app.

Comment: Why not just have the first row as column names?

Comment: As @Drackir said - column names in the first row. Then have an array that maps column name to column number. Using that you can reformat it to a standard data set.

Comment: Do you mean the first row of the CSV? I can't control what content gets put in the CSV when the companies run their exports. Some of them won't even have a heading row...
Also, even if you have a heading row, how would you import this data into a MySQL db for example, without knowing each data type? For example, which column is a date field, which is a number, which is VARCHAR, and so on... Thanks

Comment: you cant control the csv, just like you cant code an app that takes what ever csv you dump in it and make sensible rows in your database. there has to be give somewhere

Comment: I agree with you to a point. But I am saying is there a way to define a certain number of headers, and have a feature that allows the user to drag them into place, so that it is able to handle each of the different formats coming into it. It won't be accepting "what ever CSV dumped into it", there will be set of say 5 different formats. And I would like these to be able to be defined by the user.

Comment: @George: This is a pretty big thing to code, I think you'll have the best luck if you get as far as you can with it yourself and come back for help on specific issues. You're not going to get anything better than a general answer here. Just add javascript to your toolkit and you have all you need to get started on your first attempt.

Comment: I second the javascript/jQuery.  Would you be adverse to learning that too/do you already know it?

Comment: I am proficient in jQuery and Javascript. I wasn't looking for complete solutions, just some rough ideas for getting started. Each CSV format coming into the system will contain roughly similar types of material: e.g. a date field, address, postcode, etc so I could potentially make a system whereby the user specifies which column of the CSV has each bit of data needed for extraction, e.g. date is in column 2, weight is in column 6 and so on. This could then be saved as a "csv format" type record, acting as a template. This is what I wanted advice for really, at a very high level. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that users will be submitting a subset of possible data types that you define up front, this shouldn't be too tough.

A simple form that allows the user to select the data type and give you the field name in their csv could be used to create the templates you mentioned. Store these in a database table associated with the user and make them choose a template before importing a csv. For customers who have csvs without header rows, a slight variation where they tell you the column numbers for each data type.

I'd also suggest providing pre-defined formats for customers who haven't defined their exports yet. That way they could build their exports to one of your formats.

You could also let users define their default template. That way they wouldn't have to select the template every time they import data if they're always importing data in the same format.

Comment: Marked as answer, completely forgot. You don't exactly share anything in detail, and you echo largely what I thought, but on the other hand this is the best (only) answer received. So thanks for your time :)